# Make Contact Form 7 trigger a bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, contact-form-7

I have a Bootstrap based theme and I'd like the success message of [Contact Form 7](http://contactform7.com/docs/) trigger the [Bootstrap Modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) (i.e. a "popup").

I tried having the Modal sample code on my page

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            ...
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

And I assumed it would work by placing the following string in the "Additional Settings" of Contact Form 7:

```
on_sent_ok: "$('#myModal').modal(options)"
```

Unfortunately that does not result in any visible effect. Just the normal success message seems to be suppressed (it's not showing).

I would appreciate any ideas on the topic, as it doesn't seem to be featured anywhere.

Comment: do you know if a javascript error is occuring? check the developer console by pressing F12 in chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hmm, on other examples I have seen people using jQuery(), also the "options" argument will likely be undefined. try this:

```
 on_sent_ok: "jQuery('#myModal').modal()"
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: on_sent_ok and on_submit have been [officially](https://contactform7.com/additional-settings/) removed from Contact Form 7 5.0. You can use DOM events instead of these settings.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in function.php, for show a modal after form submit. Remember to set your form id.

```
 <?php add_action( 'wp_footer', 'mycustom_wp_footer' );
    function mycustom_wp_footer() { ?>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
         if ( '34' == event.detail.contactFormId ) { // Change 123 to the ID of the form 
         jQuery('#myModal').modal('show'); //this is the bootstrap modal popup id
       }
        }, false );
         </script>
       <?php  } ?>
```